# Updating Node and NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew

On a Mac OSX, I want to update to the latest versions of `node` and `npm` which is currently v10.7.0

I installed `homebrew` and executed the following at the terminal.

```
brew update
brew upgrade node
```

Now, when I type

```
node -v
```

the terminal responds:

> v6.10.2

And when I type

```
npm -v
```

the terminal responds:

> 6.2.0

It looks like I have earlier versions of Node.

But when I type

```
brew upgrade node
```

The terminal responds with

> node 10.7.0 already installed

It looks like there's a discrepancy. On one hand, it's telling me I have an earlier version of node. On the other hand, it's telling me I have the latest version.

What can I do to install and get my machine to recognize the latest node version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to link the new version using `brew link node` or `brew link --overwrite node`

Comment: You should also consider [using nvm](https://gist.github.com/MacKentoch/42be82e7f34f03edcc018b80406ca0be) to have better control over node versions

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) on my linux servers for a while and now prefer to use it (over homebrew) on my development mac as well -

```
curl --silent -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
```

Now just open a new shell (or source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh) and switch to whichever version you would like.  Eg.

```
nvm install 10.7.0
nvm use 10.7.0
```